# Using stack, make a program that determines if a pattern of characters is valid using the following rule: A^N B^N

Tags: c++, stack

In C++, the program must read the patterns to evaluate from a file called Asig5.ent. You must create a file called Asig5.sal to put the results.

I know how to work with stacks, but I don't understand the instructions at all.

I'm not asking for someone to give me a code.

I just need someone to explain to me the instructions to do it.

Comment: What part of the instructions is confusing?

Comment: What does he mean by A^N B^N?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about homework.

Comment: @uthark I thought hw questions weren't OT anymore?

Answer (score 1):

A^NB^N is likely intended as a regular-expression-looking thing. Basically, it's a string that starts with some number of As, followed immediately by exactly as many Bs.

For instance, the following strings match the pattern:

```
""
"AB"
"AABB"
"AAABBB"
```

and the following do not:

```
"A"
"B"
"AAB"
"cat"
"AABBC"
```

Exponentiation notation on strings usually means repeated concatenation, so A^2 is AA, A^3 is AAA, etc. Then the set of strings that match this pattern is {A^NB^N | N >= 0}.